# Invalidate cache on updation in table

Tags: django, database, api, caching, redis

Suppose, if I have a key in my redis cache or any other cache and there are a lots of GET queries for that key. The value of the key depends on the data in a model (table). Now if through some process the value associated with that key is updated in database then what are the ways in which I can invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) to write a receiver function to listen to the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) signal and purge the associated cache. For example:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    r.delete('item/%d' % instance.pk)
```

A more robust solution would be to use a package like [django-cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops).

Comment: hi @jacob thanks just one more thing any idea if signal is generated at almost the same time when a GET request is called, then which one will get the priority?

Comment: @UtkarshSrivastav Your Django web application workers are operating in different processes, so they shouldn't be "competing" with each other. The Redis `delete` operation should be effectively instantaneous. It shouldn't be a problem unless you're tackling a very unusual use case.

Comment: unfortunately `save()` is not the only method that can mutate a db row. `create`, `delete`, the bulk operations. some of these have their own signals, but some don't trigger a signal at all.